# Implementing oldest method

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, methods

So i am trying to implement an oldest method on this java file but the ide gives me red line under the Lot.java file where its say" if(oneArray.getYear() < small ) {
small = oneArray.getYear();"say that "cant invoke getYear() on type Car[]"  if someone can help me i seem to missing something. My strategy is that i create one array which can store the data of the 3 array and then i can iterate through the array and get the car with smallest year and return it and that would be the oldest car

```
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class A1Driver {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car[] subCompacts = {
               new Car(2019, "Orange"),
               new Car(2015, "Blue")
           };
        
        Car[] compacts = {
               new Car(),
               new Car(),
               new Car(2013, "Silver")
           };
        
        Car[] other = {
               new Car(2020, "Blue")
           };
        
        Car[] other2 = {
               new Car(2020, "Green")
           };
        
        Car[] other3 = {
               new Car(2018, "Blue")
           };
        
        Lot one = new Lot();
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(one);
        
        Lot two = new Lot(subCompacts, compacts, other);
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(two);
        
        if (!one.equals(two)){
            System.out.println("Lots one and two are different");
        }
        
        Lot three = new Lot(subCompacts, compacts, other2);
        
        if (two.equals(three)){
            System.out.println("Lots two and three are the same");
        }
        
        three = new Lot(subCompacts, compacts, other3);
        
        if (two.equals(three)){
            System.out.println("Lots two and three are the same");
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("The oldest car on lot#2 is " + two.oldestCarOnLot());
    
    }
    
}
```

this is the class file that i am writing for now i cant seem to implement oldest method which returns the oldest car on the lot

```
import java.util.Arrays;  
/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Lot {
    private int carLotNumber = 1; 
    private Car[] subCompacts; 
    private Car[] compacts; 
    private Car[] other;
    private int number;
    
    public static final Car[] SubCompacts = {
            new Car()
    };
    
    public static final Car[] Compacts = {
            new Car()
    };
    public static final Car[] Other = {
            new Car()
    };
    
    //primary constructor
    public Lot(Car[] subCompacts, Car[] compacts, Car[] other) {
        this.subCompacts = new Car[subCompacts.length];
        this.compacts = new Car[compacts.length];
        this.other = new Car[other.length];
        number= carLotNumber++;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < subCompacts.length; i++) {
            this.subCompacts[i] = new Car(subCompacts[i].getYear(),
                    subCompacts[i].getColour());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < compacts.length; i++) {
            this.compacts[i] = new Car(compacts[i].getYear(),
                    compacts[i].getColour());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < other.length; i++) {
            this.other[i] = new Car(other[i].getYear(),
                    other[i].getColour());
        }
    }
    
    
    //default constructor
    public Lot() {
        this(SubCompacts, Compacts, Other);
    }
    
    //oldest car
    public int oldestCarOnLot() {
        Car[] oneArray = new Car[subCompacts.length + compacts.length + other.length];
        int small = 5000;
        for(int i = 0; i < oneArray.length; i++) {
            if(oneArray.getYear() < small ) {
                small = oneArray.getYear();
            }
        }
    }
    
    //equals method
    public boolean equals(Lot w) {
        boolean x = subCompacts.length==w.subCompacts.length 
                && compacts.length==w.compacts.length 
                && other.length==w.other.length;
        return x;       
}
    
    //toString method
    public String toString() {
         String num1 = "Sub-Compact Cars:\r\n";
                 for(int i = 0; i < subCompacts.length; i++) {
                    num1 = num1 + "year:" + subCompacts[i].getYear() +
                        "Colour:" + subCompacts[i].getColour(); 
                 }
                String num2 = "Compact Cars:\r\n";
                 for(int i = 0; i < compacts.length; i++) {
                    num1 = num1 + "year:" + compacts[i].getYear() +
                        "Colour:" + compacts[i].getColour(); 
    }
                String num3 = "other Cars:\r\n";
                 for(int i = 0; i < other.length; i++) {
                    num1 = num1 + "year:" + other[i].getYear() +
                        "Colour:" + other[i].getColour(); 
                 }
                 String num4 = num1 + num2 + num3;
                 return num4;
    }
}
```

this is the other class file but i think this one is fine

```
    private int year;
private String colour;

//default constructor
 public Car() {
     this.year = 2022;
     this.colour = "black"; 
 }
 
 //primary constructor
 public Car(int year, String colour) {
     this.year = year;
     this.colour = colour;          
 }
 
 //getter for color
 public String getColour() {
     return this.colour;
 }

 // getter for year
 public int getYear() {
     return this.year;
 }

 //setter for colour
 public void setColour(String NewColour) {
     this.colour = NewColour;
 }

 //setter for year
 public int SetYear(int NewYear) {
     this.year = NewYear;
     return year;
 }
}
```

Comment: *the equal method which checks for same number of subcompact, compact and others on the same lot.* So if a lot contains 3 compacts, 3 subcompacts and 3 other cars, the method should return true? And if there are 1 compact, 2 subcompacts and no other cars, it should return false? Did I understand correctly? Wondering a bit because it’s not how an `equals` method traditionally works.

Comment: *i keep running into errors* We’ve all tried that. Please paste your error messages into the question so that we may help you with them (you have got an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68346789/edit) link under the question).

Comment: yes i believe that how we are supposed to do until unless i am interpretting it wrong because the equals method was suppose to returns true when each lot has the same number of sub-compact cars, the same number of compact cars, and the same number of other cars, and returns false otherwise .

Comment: I have edited my answer and added more about the `equals` method.

Answer (score 0):

> please ignore the terrible style i will edit it once the code itself actually works.

This is what we call 'putting the cart before the horse'.

The hard part about code isn't writing it, it's making it work. To debug code you must understand how it works, and if terrible style is making it hard to understand, then step 1 is to fix the terrible style. Said differently: If you have a whole forest full of trees to cut down and a dull saw, your approach seems to be: "I have no time to sharpen my saw; I have way too many trees to cut down!", which is, obviously, a very inefficient approach to it all.

> but i keep running into errors when i try to create them if someone can help me i seem to missing something.

When asking questions on Stack Overflow, if there are errors, obviously include them in your question!

> Your pasted code

Is obviously completely broken. Have you tried compiling it? For example, your `main` makes cars with `new Car(2019, "Orange")`, but your third paste which is presumably just missing `public class Car {` at the top, has only a constructor of the form `String colour, int year)`. It's like you haven't even tried, or you have pasted arbitrary snippets from across different attempts.

> It doesn't work

I see so many problems here. One major issue is that `Car` doesn't have an `equals` method which means any attempt to run e.g. `Arrays.equals(carArray1, carArray2)` just won't work - those methods work by comparing `carArray1[0]` and `carArray2[0]`, and if your Car class doesn't have an equals methods, it inherits the default definition of equality from `java.lang.Object` which you don't want, and more or less boils down that 2 cars are not equal, even if they have the same year and colour.

That, and a million compilation errors.

Fix those first. If you can't figure out what's wrong, and you see no solution other than asking SO, include the errors.

Then, add the equals method. And walk before you can run - test just the equals method first, then start adding more code. You seem to have written 5 pagefuls first, that's a bad approach. Write a small little bit, check that it compiles and does what you think it does, and then expand.

Comment: I have also worked on the code and made it better and added the error i am getting as well so maybe you can help now

Answer (score 0):

While I generally agree with what rzwitserloot said in the other answer, I will nevertheless try to give a kind of an answer to your concrete questions about finding the oldest car and the `equals` method.

**Finding the oldest car in a lot**: I don’t think you wanted the method to be static and have three parameters?

> oldest method which returns the oldest car on the lot

In your driver class you are calling the method in this way:

```
   System.out.println("The oldest car on lot#2 is " + two.oldestCarOnLot());
```

You need to decide what the method name is. You have declared `findOldestCar()`, and you are calling `oldestCarOnLot()`. Be consistent. Next, you are calling the method on an instance (`two`) and expecting a return value from that instance. So the method needs to be an instance method (non-static method) and work on the variables `subCompacts`, `compacts` and `other` declared in `Lot` rather than on parameters passed from outside. You are also calling it without any arguments, so you need to remove the parameters. Furthermore your design doesn’t make this easy for you. You need to find the oldest car in three arrays. I would recommend making the car type (compact, subcompact, other) an attribute of a car and then store all cars in one array. Searching that array for an oldest car would be simpler. For now I will take your design for granted and work with it. Declare and initialize a local variable in your `findOldestCar` method:

```
    Car oldestCarSoFar = null;
```

Now iterate the `subCompacts` array first. For each car in it:

- if `oldestCarSoFar` is null, assign the current car to `oldestCarSoFar`.
- otherwise if the current car is older than `oldestCarSoFar`, also assign the current car to `oldestCarSoFar`.

Do the same for the two other arrays. Then return `oldestCarSoFar`. If all three arrays were empty, you will be returning `null`, which is probably OK for now.

**Your `equals` method**: Edit: In your driver class you are calling the method in this way:

```
   if (!one.equals(two)){
```

So the method needs to take one argument, that is, have only one parameter. That parameter is traditionally declared to have type `Object` and override the `equals` method from the `Object` class. I suggest that you want the same here.

I suggest that you find examples of `equals` methods to take inspiration from. You will find that quite often they:

- test whether the parameter is null
- test whether the other object has the same type, either using `instanceof` or comparing the two objects’ classes

An `equals` method like all other methods that have non-void return type needs to return a value in *all* cases. So make sure that for all possible cases you have decided whether you should return `true` or `false`.

If I understand correctly that only the *count* of cars of each type count, not the actual cars, then you need to compare the lengths of the arrays and you don’t need `Arrays.equals()`. Maybe I misunderstood this detail, though.

Comment: I have also worked on the code and made it better but i am still curious as to how you can implement the oldest method from what you sugested because i did attempt it but i cant seem to figure out the new error its giving